# Can't return the assigned value

Tags: angular, typescript

I have such a function;

```
getList() {
    this.http.get(this.rootURL )
    .toPromise().then(res => { this.mimeList = res as Mime[];
                               this.arrayLenght = this.mimeList.length;
    });
    return this.arrayLenght;
  }
```

In this function, I want to return the lenght of the `mimeList` array. The variable `arrayLength` is used to store the length value and declared in the body of the class like this;

```
export class MimeService {
         .
         .
         .
         .
  arrayLenght = 0;
         .
         .
         .
         .
         .
         .
}
```

When I place a `console.log` statement inside of the `this.http.get(this.rootURL ).toPromise().then` body, it prints me the real length of the array. So it means, there is no problem for retrieving the length of this array. However, in the other class where I am calling the `getList()` function;

```
export class AssetListComponent implements OnInit {
             .
             .
             .
             .
             .
             .
ngOnInit() {
  this.service.getList();
  this.serviceCountry.getList();
  this.databaseLength = this.serviceMime.getList();
}
             .
             .
             .
             .
             .
             .
}
```

The returned value is **"0"** instead of the real length of the array. I can see this when I run `console.log(this.databaseLength)`.

Where I am wrong? I am very new in Typescript and most probably the answer of this question is very easy. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's not how asynchronous stuff works. Your `Promise` needs to be resolved before you return any value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
async getList() {
    const res = await this.http.get(this.rootURL ).toPromise();
    this.mimeList = await res as Mime[];
    this.arrayLenght = this.mimeList.length;
    return this.arrayLenght;
}
```

Change your getList() function like this. You should wait until your promise gets resolved. In your other class add the await keyword before calling getList();

```
this.databaseLength = await this.serviceMime.getList();
```

Comment: I am getting the following error; `Type 'Promise<number>' is not assignable to type 'number'`

Comment: Can you check in which line you are getting this error?

Comment: The error occurs when I am assigning the returned value of `getList()` to the other class' variable. `this.databaseLength = this.serviceMime.getList();`

Comment: in your other class 
this.databaseLength = await this.serviceMime.getList(); do like this. I have also edited my answer